# Multiple namespaces with Composer

Tags: composer-php

### The goal

Using `Test` and `Mobile` namespaces for different directories with **Composer**.

### The problem

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Application\Test\Unit in [...] on line 9

### The scenario

**composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Test": "private/app/",
        "Mobile": "private/app/"
    }
}
```

Someone can give me an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring autoloading for classes inside the namespace `Application` in your composer.json, so the error must be outside of Composer.